# JQuery unknown "this" inside ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to change class attribute when ajax request has been made, but I can't access "this" inside Ajax request

```
$('.shopping').click(function(){
        //Get id attribute
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        //Send id attribute in Ajax request
        $.get('processAddToShopping.php?id='+id, function(data){
        if(data == "success"){
           //Change attribute if success
           $(this).attr('class', 'new'); //CAN'T access "this" anymore
        }
        });
});
```

Comment: oh but you can access `this` ... it's just not what you want it to be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a context variable:

```
$('.shopping').click(function(){
    //Get id attribute
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var that = this;

    //Send id attribute in Ajax request
    $.get('processAddToShopping.php?id='+id, function(data){
        if(data == "success"){
       //Change attribute if success
            $(that).attr('class', 'new'); 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have 'id' attribute, you can find the DOM element by id :)

```
 $("#"+id).attr('class', 'new');
```